# Find values string inside a string on google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm having some difficulty to extract the information inside the string.

For example, I would like to have the entire line where I have "MODERATE: harm/physical violence/physical abuse [220]", actually the line where I have the code [220].

An example, I have this text on the column BS

```
"NONE: sexual/anatomy/nudity [152],
NONE: sexual/sex acts [100],
NONE: language/profanity [400],
NONE: harm/physical violence/moment of death [227],
MODERATE: harm/physical violence/physical abuse [220],
NONE: modifier/intent/edsa [902],
NONE: modifier/video games [963],
NONE: modifier/music video [960],
NONE: modifier/news [961]"
```

and I would like to take out those parts separeted with the following codes (not the entire information):

**NONE: sexual/anatomy/nudity [152]**

**NONE: sexual/sex acts [100]**

**NONE: language/profanity [400]**

**MODERATE: harm/physical violence/physical abuse [220]**

But I need to be aware cause sometimes the information doesnt come on this way, it may change and also have other information.

Here is a test sheet with some information and the expected result

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16fA2e3e6fm-xwkFek28pJ2VHL4F_fiYWvkIVmDuFNEo/edit?usp=sharing

[image]

Comment: what do you really want ? can you give an example output ? the text is a bit confusing

Comment: Sorry, I edited to have an example of the final thing

Comment: *"...sometimes the information doesn't come on this way, it may change and also have other information"*. This is way too vague. What do you mean? Please do not explain in words. Please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) with expected results so as you can be easier helped.

Comment: Thanks, I'll created and shate the test sheet, thanks for the informaiton

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for Text to Column behaviour? Splitting that string at each comma. https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6325535

Comment: I added the link for the test sheet

Comment: And @Aerials, I thought to use split, but I wanna try to avoid to add more columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see if the following meets your needs

In cell `D4` place the following formula

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(if(LEN(A4:A),IF(--REGEXEXTRACT(A4:A, ""&D2&"")=D2,REGEXEXTRACT(A4:A, ".*\["&D2&"\]")),"")))
```

Then adjust for the rest cells `E4`, `F4`, etc accordingly

Comment: is exactly what I would like to use, thank you so much for your time and effort